# What is the purpose of the `iterator-sentinel-pair` concept in [ranges.subrange]?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

What's the purpose of the exposition-only `iterator-sentinel-pair` concept as defined in [[range.subrange]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange)?

```cpp
template<class T> 
concept iterator-sentinel-pair = // exposition only 
  !range<T> && pair-like<T> && 
  sentinel_for<tuple_element_t<1, T>, tuple_element_t<0, T>>;
```

The only time it's used, as far as I can see, is for CTAD, such as in

```cpp
template<iterator-sentinel-pair P>
  subrange(P) -> subrange<tuple_element_t<0, P>, tuple_element_t<1, P>>;
```

However, there aren't any constructors of `std::ranges::subrange` that will work with this concept: the only real constructor possibly fitting this parameter list is [this one](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange#ctor-6):

```cpp
template<not-same-as<subrange> R> 
  requires borrowed_range<R> &&
           convertible-to-non-slicing<iterator_t<R>, I> &&
           convertible_to<sentinel_t<R>, S>
constexpr subrange(R&& r) requires (!StoreSize || sized_range<R>);
```

which requires (through `borrowed_range<R>`) that we have `range<R>`... but `iterator-sentinel-pair` explicitly requires `not range<R>`!

It looks to me that the intention was to allow code along the lines of

```cpp
std::multiset foo = // ...
auto result = foo.equal_range(key);  // an iterator-sentinel pair
for (auto value : std::ranges::subrange(result)) {
  // ...
}
```

but this clearly will not compile, as `std::pair<It, It>` doesn't fulfil the requirements for `std::range`. Maybe the constructor to allow for this use-case was overlooked?

Is there some other purpose I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the purpose of the exposition-only iterator-sentinel-pair concept as defined in [range.subrange]?

No purpose anymore, they're removed as of [LWG 3404](https://wg21.link/lwg3404) adopted at the previous plenary, and will shortly be removed from the draft. They're just vestigial oversight after the all the stuff that used them was removed in [LWG 3281](https://wg21.link/lwg3281).

---

*Originally*, the purpose of the concept was precisely to allow this:

```cpp
for (auto value : std::ranges::subrange(foo.equal_range(key))) {
    // ...
}
```

but the implicitness was removed based on the reasoning that:

> Just because a pair is holding two iterators, it doesn't mean those two iterators denote a valid range. Implicitly converting such pair-like types to a subrange is dangerous and should be disallowed.

Though it seems useful to at least have an *explicit* conversion. Thankfully, it's straightforward to write ourselves:

```cpp
template <typename P>
    requires (std::tuple_size_v<P> == 2)
          && std::ranges::sentinel_for<std::tuple_element_t<1, P>,
                                       std::tuple_element_t<0, P>>
auto make_subrange_from_pair(P pair) {
    // either this
    auto [b, e] = pair;
    return subrange(b, e);
    // or that
    return subrange(std::get<0>(pair), std::get<1>(pair));
}
```